# How to prove which of the following functions has the greater growth rate

Tags: big-o

I came across this question. To prove whether the following statement was true or false
Let f(n) = n + log n, then f(n) = O(log^2 n).

I'm unsure as to how I can go about proving or disproving whether log^2n is the upper bound for n or not. Could someone help me construct a proof for the same.

Comment: Hint: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function

```
g(x) = x(ln x)^2      ; x > 0
```

This function is positive and increasing for `0 < x < e^(-2)`.

To see why this is true, let's calculate its derivative:

```
g'(x) = 1*(ln x)^2 + x*2(ln x)/x
```

basically because the derivative of `ln x` is `1/x`. Then

```
g'(x) = (ln x)((ln x) + 2)
```

which is positive for `0 < x < e^(-2)`, since both factors are negative in that interval.

This proves that `g(x)` is positive and increasing in the interval `(0, e^(-2))`. Therefore, there exists a positive constant `c` such that

```
g(x) > c      ; if x is small enough
```

which implies that

```
g(1/n) > c    ; if n is large enough
```

or

```
(1/n)(ln n)^2 > c
```

or

```
n < (1/c)(ln n)^2 = O((ln n)^2)
```

and since `ln n` is also `O((ln n)^2)` we get

```
n + (ln n) = O((ln n)^2)
```

as we wanted to see.

Comment: We know the growth rate of square root of n > log n. So if you were to square on both sides, Wouldn't n be > log^ 2 n?

Comment: @JerricoKyle Yes, but that would show that `n^2 > (log n)^2`, while what you want is to show that `n <= c(log n)^2`. So I don't think that squaring both sides would help.

Comment: I meant square root of n / Square of root n would become n

Comment: @JerricoKyle Sorry, I had misunderstood you. Anyway, how would you prove that `sqrt(n)` is `<` or `>` than `log(n)`?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/42038294/is-complexity-ologn-equivalent-to-osqrtn

Comment: @JerricoKyle That's a nice explanation indeed.